# get omdbapi info in url

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this code on mysite.com/imdb.php

```
   <?php
    $movie_id = 'tt0387564';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' . $movie_id . '&plot=short&apikey=MY_APY_KEY') , true);
    $data2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' . $movie_id . '?api_key=MY_APY_KEY') , true);
    if (empty($movie_id))
    {
        echo '';
        die();
    }
    
    echo '
    <div class="container">
    <div class="poster"><img src="' . $data['Poster'] . '"/></div>
    <div class="Title">' . $data['Title'] . '</div>
    <div class="Year">' . $data['Year'] . '</div>
    <div class="Genre">' . $data['Genre'] . '</div>
    <div class="imdbRating">' . $data['imdbRating'] . '</div>
    <div class="Director">' . $data['Director'] . '</div>
    <div class="Actors">' . $data['Actors'] . '</div>
    <div class="overview">' . $data2['overview'] . '</div>
    </div>
    ';
    ?>
```

Now how can i get informations in url without changing the php file everytime, like this mysite.com/imdb.php?movieid=tt0387564

Comment: Either POST or GET the value to that script, then use the reference.

Comment: thanks for the response, its something like this yes, but i dont have php knowledge to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Append the following code to the beginning of the script.
Get more, see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['movieid'])) {
    die('require param movieid');
}
$movie_id = $_GET['movieid'];

// debug
// var_dump($movie_id); die;
```